Convergence of modulus of a approximating sequence in $H^1_0(\Omega)$
Let $u \in H^1_0(\Omega)$ and consider $u_n \in C^\infty_0(\Omega)$ such that $\|u_n - u\|_{H^1(\Omega)} \to 0$. I know $|u| \in H^1(\Omega)$. I would like to know if $|u_n| \to |u|$ in $H^1(\Omega)$. Actually, I don't know if this is true or not.
My attempt: I know
$$
\partial_{x_i}|u|(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\partial_{x_i}u(x), u(x) > 0 \\
0, u(x) = 0\\
-\partial_{x_i}u(x), u(x) < 0
\end{cases}
$$
Notice that
$$
\int_{\Omega} ||u_n|-|u||^2 \leq \int_{\Omega} |u_n-u|^2 \to 0.
$$
So, $|u_n| \to |u|$ in $L^2(\Omega)$. I got stuck in the part
$$
(1) \quad \int_{\Omega} |\nabla (|u_n| - |u|)|^2 \to 0.
$$
Any help to prove or disapprove (1) is welcome.

Let $u^+:= \max(u,0) = \frac12(u+|u|)$, $u^- = \min(u,0) = \frac12(u-|u|)$.
Using the formula for the gradient of $|u|$, we can compute $\nabla u^+$ and $\nabla u^-$ to prove
$$
\nabla u(x) = \nabla u^+(x) + \nabla u^-(x) = 0
$$
for almost all $x$ such that $u(x)=0$.
The converging sequence $(u_n)$ has a subsequence such that $\nabla u_{n_k} \to \nabla u$ almost everywhere, and there is a dominating function $g\in L^2$ such that $|\nabla u| \le g$ almost everywhere (check the book by Brezis or the standard proof of completeness of $L^p$-spaces).
Now we can use dominated convergence to prove $ \nabla |u_{n_k}| \to \nabla |u|$ in $L^2$.
It is easy to see that $\nabla |u_{n_k}| (x) \to \nabla |u|(x)$ for almost all $x$ with $u(x) \ne 0$. If $u(x)=0$ then $\nabla u(x)=0$ and $\nabla |u_{n_k}| (x) \to 0 = \nabla |u|(x)$ (this is for almost all such $x$).
Then dominated convergence proves $\int \big| \nabla |u_{n_k}| (x) -\nabla |u|(x)\big|^2 dx \to 0$.
Using a standard subsequence-subsequence argument, one gets $\int \big| \nabla |u_{n}| (x) -\nabla |u|(x)\big|^2 dx \to 0$.

If $x$ is such that $u(x) >0$, then $u_{n_k}(x) > 0$ for large $k$. And if $u(x) < 0$ then $u_{n_k}(x) < 0$ for large $k$. So I understand $\nabla |u_{n_k}| (x)| \to \nabla |u|(x)$ for almost $x$ with $u(x) \neq 0$. However, defining $A = {u \in \Omega : u(x) = 0}$, how can I show that $\nabla |u_{n_k}| \to 0$ almost everywhere in $A$?

Given $x \in A$, supposing  w.l.g., $u(x) > 0$, one has $\nabla |u_{n_k}|(x) = \nabla u_{n_k}(x) \to \nabla u(x)$, almost everywhere. So, how to show that $\nabla u(x)  = 0$ for almost everywhere $x \in A$

I think I have an idea: As $u = u^+ - u^-$, almost everywhere we know $\nabla u = \nabla u^{+} - \nabla u^{-}$. We also know, there is $N$ with zero measure such that $\nabla u^{+}(x) = \nabla u (x)$ if $u(x) > 0$ and $\nabla u^{+}(x) = 0$ if $u(x) \leq 0$, for all $x \not\in N$. Also $\nabla u^{-}(x) = -\nabla u (x)$ if $u(x) < 0$ and $\nabla u^{-}(x) = 0$ if $u(x) \geq 0$, for all $x \not\in N$. Thus if we take $x \in A\backslash N$, then $\nabla u(x) = 0$. Is it correct?

yes, exactly. $\nabla u(x)=0$ for almost all $x$ for which $u(x) =0$.
