How to show that the operation of taking absolute value is a continuous map on $H^1(U)$?
Let $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a connected bounded open set with smooth boundary. Denote by $H^1(U)$ the Sobolev space consisting of those real-valued functions that are square summable and whose weak derivatives are also square summable. The norm on $H^1(U)$ is induced by the inner product
$$\left\langle u,v\right\rangle=\int_{U}(uv+\nabla u\cdot \nabla v) dx$$
Now I would like to check that the map $\text{abs}: H^1(U)\to H^1(U)$ defined by $\text{abs}(f)=|f|$, the absolute value of $f$, is continuous.
I have checked that this map is well-defined, that's if $f\in H^1(U)$ then $|f|\in H^1(U),$ in fact, the weak derivative of $|f|$ can we written as $\mathrm{sgn}(f)\nabla f.$ So it remains to show that such a map is continuous. But when I taking a sequence $\left\{f_n\right\}\subset H^1(U)$ that converges to $f$ in $H^1(U),$ I found the derivative term
$$\int_{U}(\nabla f-\nabla f_n)\cdot(\nabla f-\nabla f_n)dx$$
is hard to be demonstrated to converge to zero. Can someone help me? Any help is highly appreciated!
RMK: I also recall the following famous result on functional analysis (theorem $5.3$ on Helmut H.Schaefer's book "Banach Lattices and Positive Operators"): Let $E,F$ be normed vector lattices and suppose $E$ is norm complete, then every positive linear map $T: E\to F$ is continuous. In this question the operator $\mathrm{abs}$ is positive (but not linear) and $\left\|\mathrm{abs}(f)\right\|\leq \left\|f\right\|$, I'm wondering whether or nor there is similar theorem for nonlinear positive operator that can be applied.

Take subsequence such that $f_n$ and $\nabla f_n$ converges pointwise a.e., then use dominated convergence.

see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4923292/convergence-of-modulus-of-a-approximating-sequence-in-h1-0-omega/4923509#4923509
